# Retrieve Distributions lists from Active Directory with LDAP / PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have an LDAP annuary working on Active Directory (Win Server 2008). I try to connect to this AD with PHP (and LDAP lib) and retrieve all distributions lists from a specific OU.

The connection and authentication is working, but when I want to retrieve the lists from OU, I dont have any results (rights are OK and in local it's working too, without PHP)

Here is my code :

```
$ldap_host = "ip.add.re.ss";
$ldap_dn = "OU=Listes,DC=domain,DC=tld"; // all there infos are ok
$base_dn = "DC=domain,DC=tld";
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

$user = 'username'; $password = '';
$filter="(sAMAccountName=recette)";
$filter="(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(OU=Lists))";

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $password);
$results = ldap_search($ldap,$base_dn, $filter);
$member_list = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
```

If I delete the OU=Lists, it's working, I have results, but the one I want. Then, when I add the OU=Lists, I don't have any results.

Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Is it `"OU=Listes` like in your code, or `OU=Lists` like in your description ?

Comment: Yes sorry, it was Listes but I traduced in english except here. But yes, I'm looking to retrieve "Listes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are trying to "Retrieve Distributions lists" and yet your LDAP filter is to retrieve users which have the attribute ou=Lists:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(OU=Lists))
```

Try an LDAP filter as:

```
(&(objectCategory=Group)(proxyAddresses=*))
```

more like these are at:
http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches